# Imgur API 3 uploading to account PHP

Tags: php, curl, oauth, imgur

I have the following code uploading anonymously just fine but I cannot seem to figure out for the life of me how to login to my account to upload. I see you need to use OAuth and need to refresh your token every hour but this is something I cannot seem to get my head around as I wouldn't know where to start.

```
$handle = fopen($file_tmp, "r");
$data = fread($handle, $file_size);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Client-ID ' . $client_id));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('image' => base64_encode($data)));
    $reply = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$reply = json_decode($reply);
$url = $reply->data->link;
```

Source: https://api.imgur.com/oauth2